# Customized Login site not showing in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, customization

I have created a Django App and want to provide a custom Login page with only the possibility to use a Google login.

I have implemented the Google login based on this post: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/
It actually works fine and when I hit localhost/account/login I am getting a login page:
[image: Django standard login screen]

I actually do not want a sign up and a "local" sign in option, I only need a Google login.

To achieve this I have created the following folder structure to overwrite the login template (based on https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial):
MyApp/templaltes/registration/login.html

[image: Folder structure]

login.html has the following content:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load socialaccount %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <center><h1>{% trans 'LoginHeading' %}</h1></center>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome, You are logged in as {{ user.username }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login With Google</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have also added 'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))] to the TEMPLATES section in settings.py.

Unfortunately I am still seeing the Django default login page. What am I missing?

(I have also restarted the dev server to make sure it is not an issue there with the same result)

Comment: Did u find the solution. Answers shown below are not working

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. After reading the documentation of Allauth throughly I found this:

> For instance, the view corresponding to the account_login URL uses the
> template account/login.html. If you create a file with this name in
> your code layout, it can override the one shipped with allauth.

So I changed the folder structure to account/login.html and it works.

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: @ajinzrathod Have you figured it out?

Comment: Yes, add this line at end of **settings.py**: `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True`. Don't forget to run migration command after that.

Answer (score 1):

To do this thing you can simply create an account folder under the template and add login.html  inside it.
This will override your login page.
**Make sure that folder name must be account**.

In your case, you can rename your folder from "registration" to "account".
Like following:
[image]

I am sure this will work well.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to add

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
```

to your **settings.py** and it should skip/bypass the sign up form.

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70680165/11605100

---

**Still does not work?**

Stop the server and then;

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py runserver
```